# Is there any way to define a range like getRange(predeterminedRow, [range of columns])?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, range

Basically self explanatory. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to set a range using a predetermined row from a search operation in the function, and for the columns, a range of columns. I essentially want it to grab the entire defined row. Does anyone know how to do this?

Basically: I have a search run. The search gives me the row in which the search term was found. I just want to getRange of that entire defined row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var determinedRow = 1;
var range = sheet.getRange(determinedRow, 1, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns())
```

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation,

**getRange(row, column, numRows)**

Returns the range with the top left cell at the given coordinates, and with the given number of rows.

*Parameters*

Name    Type    Description

**row** Integer The starting row index of the range; row indexing starts with 1.

**column**  Integer The column index of the range; column indexing starts with 1.

**numRows** Integer The number of rows to return.

*Return*
**Range** — A range containing a single column of data with the number of rows specified.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow-column-numrows

**for you problem getRange(predetermineRow,predetermineColumn,cantRowYouNeed)**

if you need ALL rows regardless of content. use **getMaxColumns()**

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getMaxColumns()

good luck